# How to export java app with libraries properly (intellij)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I cannot get export settings in intellij to work. In editor my application works fine. When I am building artifacts, there are no errors too.

But when I run the exported jar:

> java -jar Pogoda.jar

What I see is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
        at piotr.bartela.Settings.load(Settings.java:63)
        at piotr.bartela.Controller.main(Controller.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

There is my configuration:
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K23Md.jpg)

My question is: What do I missing?

> I found the solution!

There is a difference between: adding a library, and adding extracted library in the Artifacts tab. In first case, executable jar did not work; in second, it works perfectly.

Comment: You have to link all those jars to the classpath. You can do this in module dependencies  list.

Comment: It did not help. 
This is how it looks right now: https://i.imgur.com/kVkd9Ra.png

Comment: I got this! Thanks for suggestion but problem was in the artifacts tab.